# Object Expected when Targeting CheckBox Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox, jscript

I have the following script, which successfully changes the value of a checkbox (this toggles whether or not the user in in a certain skype response group):

```
var ie = WSH.CreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
    url = "https://lyncfeg.DOMAIN.COM/RgsClients/Tab.aspx",

ie.visible = true;
ie.Navigate(url);
while (ie.readyState != 4) WSH.Sleep(25);

var element = ie.document.getElementById('ctl05_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl01');
element.click();
WSH.Sleep(25);

ie.quit()
```

I would like to incorporate a simple message confirming to the user whether or not it worked:

```
var element = ie.document.getElementById('ctl05_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl01');
var value = element.value;
alert(value);
```

But I see this error on the line with `alert(value);`

> Script:  C:\Users\User.Name\Source\Repos\Scripts\Useful\Toggle-ITSupportResponseGroup.js
>
> Line:    14
>
> Char:    1
>
> Error:   Object expected
>
> Code:    800A138F
>
> Source:  Microsoft JScript runtime error

Here is the html for the checkbox:

```
<INPUT onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl05$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl01\',\'\')', 0)" 
    id=ctl05_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_ctl01 
    type=checkbox value="" 
    name=ctl05$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$ctl01>
```

With `value="on"` and `CHECKED="checked"` if the checkbox is active.

Why am i seeing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an answer to this, but also tried:

```
ie.window.alert
ie.document.window.alert
ie.document.alert
```

thinking that I may have to call `alert` in the context of the window I created.

In the end, I just used `WScript.Echo` which seems to work fine.